# In Superman: Red Son, can Lazarenko be translated into Lang?

Tags: dc, superman, translation

In *Superman: Red Son*, is "Lana Lazarenko", the name of his childhood girl friend, a transposition of "Lana Lang"?

Both of them are called Lana, of course, and they both come from his childhood city -- Smallville for "regular" Superman, the same Ukrainian kolkhoz for red son.

But what is the meaning of "Lazarenko"? Could it be literally translated to "Lang"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**It was a Ukrainian surname circulating in the news at the time**

While the match with Lana Lang is probably intentional, the exact choice of "Lazarenko" had likely no hidden meaning.

The comic Red Son was published in 2003. Around this period, the former Ukrainian prime minister [Pavlo Lazarenko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pavlo_Lazarenko), an ally of the more famous Yulia Tymoshenko, was detained in the US on corruption charges. 
It's a fair guess that the british Mark Millar, author of Red Son, then simply picked up the Ukrainian surname in the news.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation about the context !